# Should I use crateTable() or sync() in node Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

In Sequelize I can use createTable() in a migration or sync() to create my db tables. Is it better to use one method or the other for creating tables?

Answer (score 0):

I think using `sync()` is better unless you need to seed a table in which case use `createTable()` in the migration and then seed. If you use use `createTable()` then you need to maintain the schema for the object in two places which is a bit redundant.